# net/http renders the root route even when I go to a route which doesn't exist

Tags: go

I have these routes:

```
  http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderAndExecuteTemplate(w, r, "page/index.tmpl", nil)
  })

  http.HandleFunc("/route1", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderAndExecuteTemplate(w, r, "page/route1.tmpl", nil)
  })


  http.HandleFunc("/route2", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderAndExecuteTemplate(w, r, "page/route2.tmpl", nil)
  })
```

It works.

However, when I go to a route which doesn't exist: "localhost/fdsafdsafdsfds", it still renders the "index" page.

Why? How to prevent it from that?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux):

> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree,
>   the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered
>   patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

One way to prevent this is to build a handler that looks at the request:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  if r.URL.Path != "/" {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    return
  }

  renderAndExecuteTemplate(w, r, "page/index.tmpl", nil)
})
```